# Как отключить все предупреждения, кроме интересующих?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang, warning

Хочу посмотреть только на нужные мне варнинги, игнорируя остальные. Как это сделать в `gcc` и `clang`?

Допустим, мне нужен варнинг `-Wnarrowing`. Пишу `gcc -w -Wnarrowing`, ожидая, что все варнинги кроме последнего будут пропущены, но указанный варнинг тоже пропускается.

Также пробовал опцию `-Werror=narrowing`, но она не совсем подходит, т.к. делает из предупреждений ошибки, что не позволяет игнорировать некоторые из них, останавливая компиляцию ещё до того, как все интересующие места найдены.

Comment: Отключайте ненужные через `-Wno-<...>`